# Python print first N integers from a string

Tags: python

Is it possible without regex in python to print the first n integers from a string containing both integers and characters?

For instance:

```
string1 = 'test120202test34234e23424'
string2 = 'ex120202test34234e23424'

foo(string1,6)  => 120202
foo(string2,6) => 120202
```

Comment: anything is possible in python

Comment: Why would you do it without a regex?

Comment: you can just measure the ascii value, if its 0x30-0x39 or whatever thats a number (go check i think 0x30-39 is right but i might be wrong)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, a better question is "why would you use a regex?". =)

Comment: `str` is not a good name for a variable as it shadows a built-in function.

Comment: What if the input is `str, 7`?

Comment: You may get a lot of hints here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams regex makes me cringe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove all the alphabets from you string with `str.translate` and the slice till the number of digits you want, like this

```
import string

def foo(input_string, num):
    return input_string.translate(None, string.letters)[:num]

print foo('test120202test34234e23424', 6)   # 120202
print foo('ex120202test34234e23424',   6)   # 120202
```

**Note:** This simple technique works only in Python 2.x

But the **most efficient way** is to go with the `itertools.islice`

```
from itertools import islice

def foo(input_string, num):
    return "".join(islice((char for char in input_string if char.isdigit()),num))
```

This is is the most efficient way because, it doesn't have to process the entire string before returning the result.

Comment: Naw, the most efficient way is to write a C extension. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Anything's possible without a regex. Most things are *preferable* without a regex.

On easy way is.

```
>>> str = 'test120202test34234e23424'
>>> str2 = 'ex120202test34234e23424'
>>> ''.join(c for c in str if c.isdigit())[:6]
'120202'
>>> ''.join(c for c in str2 if c.isdigit())[:6]
'120202'
```

You might want to handle your corner cases some specific way -- it all depends on what you know your code should do.

```
>>> str3 = "hello 4 world"
>>> ''.join(c for c in str3 if c.isdigit())[:6]
'4'
```

And don't name your strings `str`!

Comment: I would recommend doing a break down of `''.join(c for c in str3 if c.isdigit())[:6]`.  It's a lot to take in if you are new to Python

Comment: Someone else can if they want -- http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21802062/edit -- but I'll just leave a few hints right here for someone who wants to do their own legwork: 1. Strings iterate over their characters, (`c` stands for character above), 2. the weird `x for x in xs if foo(x)` notation is a "generator expression" (a similar concept is the "list comprehension"), and 3. the `foo[:6]` notation is "slicing".

Comment: Good enough for me.  +1

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want to process the whole string - not a problem with the length of strings you give as an example - you could try:

```
import itertools
"".join(itertools.islice((c for c in str2 if c.isdigit()),0,5))
```

Comment: BTW, the start argument is optional if it's 0 -- http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice